# Why do I have to press on my button twice to bring up the in app purchase screen in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have two in app purchase buttons one to unlock level one and the other to unlock level two. When I press on either button the first time nothing happens. If I press on either buttons again the second time then the in app purchase screen comes up to handle the payments. Why does this happen and how could I get it to work the first time I press the button? Heres the code I have with my buttons: IF you need more code or more information please let me know!

```
 if node.name == "unlockleveltwobutton" {

        for product in list {
            var prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if(prodID == "unlockLevelTwo") {
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break;

            }
        }
        runAction(menuAudioPlayer)
        unlockLevel()
    }


    if node.name == "unlocklevelthreebutton" {

        for product in list {
            var prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if(prodID == "unlockLevelThree") {
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break;
            }
        }
        runAction(menuAudioPlayer)
        unlockLevel()






    }
```

Comment: Where should I set the breakpoint? I never used it before.

Comment: I think I know why...it might be because I have two in app purchases and I have to press on the button twice to confirm which one I want to buy. Could you take a look at my code please?

Comment: got it to work I put this if statement inside of a function instead of call it ahead of time in my didMoveToView.